# How does this flatten algorithm not forget the variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, flatten

i was messing around to flattening an array and i ended up writting something like this

```
const arr = [1,[[4,5],4,[9,8]]];

const result = [];
const flatten = arr =>
{

    arr.forEach(elem =>{
        if(Array.isArray(elem))
        {
            flatten(elem);
        }
        else{
            result.push(elem);
        }
    })
    return result;
}


console.log(flatten(arr))
```

then i googled the solution and i found a solution that looked more like this.

```
const arr = [1,[[4,5],4,[9,8]]];


const flatten = arr =>
{
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach(elem =>{
        if(Array.isArray(elem))
        {
            result = result.concat(flatten(elem));
        }
        else{
            result.push(elem);
        }
    })
    return result;
}


console.log(flatten(arr))
```

as you can see the `result` variable is in the function, but then the function is recursive, how is it being saved ? thank you.

Comment: `result` is declared for each recursive cycle as an empty array, but lets say  we are at the end of recursive cycle, at that time we will have `8` as the element we will add that `8` in empty `result` which will be like `result = [8]`, now when we return back one step, we will go to line `result = result.concat([8]);` now here again in this context `result` is empty which will get concatenated with [8], same process will be followed back till the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this code and follow the logs. You will understand how recursion works.

```js
const arr = [1,[[4,5],4,[9,8]]];


(flatten = arr =>
{
    let result = [];
    console.log(`initialized result for element ${arr} ${result}`)
    arr.forEach(elem =>{
        if(elem.length)
        {   console.log(`updating result if we get an array ${result.length}`)
            result = result.concat(flatten(elem));
            console.log(`result updated in case of array ${result}`)
        }
        else{
            console.log(`updating result if we get a number ${result.length}`)
            result.push(elem);
            console.log(`result updated in case of number ${result}`)
        }
    })
    return result;
})(arr)
```